# resize canvas and paint on right place

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a canvas and I have loaded an Image on canvas. I can paint on the canvas
but in small browser size, some part of canvas will be hidden. So i have
used jQuery resize and it resize the canvas and show full image inside it and this is fine .
It resize canvas and full image is displayed. However, If I now paint on it , it paints/draws
far away the actual place. It happens only in resizing canvas but not on the full width of
browser. Is there any way to solve this issue.
I am looking for a ways to resize canvas and show full image on small device and should paint on actual place not far away.
Initially I want to show abit bigger canvas of width alteast 800px and height 400px

```
  <canvas data-fieldid="1" id="can-1"class="image-canvas"></canvas>
```

Below is the js code that allows user to draw on image of canvas

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
sdsdfds
<script>
        var  flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "red",
        y = 3;

    function init(fieldId) {
        //fieldId are multiple Ids, but I get here one at a time 
        let canvas = document.getElementById('can-' + fieldId);
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ratio = 400 / 800;
        canvas.width =
        document.body.clientWidth < 800 ? document.body.clientWidth : 800;
        canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;


        let base_image = new Image();
        base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
        base_image.src = document.getElementById('image_' + fieldId).src
        base_image.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(base_image,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

        };
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
            findxy('move', e, this)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
            findxy('down', e, this)

        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
            findxy('up', e, this)

        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
            findxy('out', e, this)

        }, false);
    }
    function draw(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function findxy(res, e,c) {
        let ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - c.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            currY = e.clientY - c.getBoundingClientRect().top;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - c.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                currY = e.clientY - c.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                draw(ctx);
            }
        }
    }

    

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".image-canvas").each(function(canvas) {
       
            init($(this).data("fieldid"));
        });
       
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is CSS. When using 100% width and heights you will have issues. You can set the image width to the `clientWidth` and use the image ratio to maintain aspect. Use an event listener for `resize` to have the canvas change size is a browser is resized. Using an if statment we can have a max width of 800 and anything less is the clientWidth.

You mouse position should now be accurate without CSS.

```js
var flag = false,
  prevX = 0,
  currX = 0,
  prevY = 0,
  currY = 0,
  dot_flag = false,
  ratio;

var x = "red",
  y = 3;

function init(fieldId) {
  //fieldId are multiple Ids, but I get here one at a time
  let canvas = document.getElementById("can-" + fieldId);
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ratio = 400 / 800;
  canvas.width =
    document.body.clientWidth < 800 ? document.body.clientWidth : 800;
  canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;

  let base_image = new Image();
  base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  base_image.src = document.getElementById("image_" + fieldId).src;
  base_image.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  };
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mousemove",
    function (e) {
      findxy("move", e, this);
    },
    false
  );
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mousedown",
    function (e) {
      findxy("down", e, this);
    },
    false
  );
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mouseup",
    function (e) {
      findxy("up", e, this);
    },
    false
  );
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mouseout",
    function (e) {
      findxy("out", e, this);
    },
    false
  );
  
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    resizeCanvas(canvas)
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  })
}
function draw(ctx) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
  ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = x;
  ctx.lineWidth = y;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function findxy(res, e, c) {
  let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  if (res == "down") {
    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
    currX = e.clientX - c.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    currY = e.clientY - c.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    flag = true;
    dot_flag = true;
    if (dot_flag) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = x;
      ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
      ctx.closePath();
      dot_flag = false;
    }
  }
  if (res == "up" || res == "out") {
    flag = false;
  }
  if (res == "move") {
    if (flag) {
      prevX = currX;
      prevY = currY;
      currX = e.clientX - c.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      currY = e.clientY - c.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      draw(ctx);
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".image-canvas").each(function (canvas) {
    //console.log($(this).data("fieldid"))
    init($(this).data("fieldid"));
  });
});

function resizeCanvas(canvas) {
    ratio = 400 / 800;
  canvas.width =
    document.body.clientWidth < 800 ? document.body.clientWidth : 800;
  canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
}
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas data-fieldid='1'  
id="can-1"
class="image-canvas"
style="position:absolute;top:10px;border:1px dotted;">
</canvas>
<canvas data-fieldid='2'  
id="can-2"
class="image-canvas"
style="position:absolute;top:450px;border:1px dotted;">
</canvas>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3VucmlzZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt='view' id="image_1" class="images" />
<img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/colored-powder-explosion-abstract-closeup-dust-on-backdrop-colorful-picture-id1072093690?k=6&m=1072093690&s=612x612&w=0&h=Eyk67XBt4sr3Bk1MubM6dHpvEVNICX4L7FumWhcTwuY=" alt='view' id="image_2" class="images" />
```

Comment: thanks for valid answer. I made some changes, Now  my init() method accepts canvasId also. How can I do based on this situation. I did like this   window.addEventListener('resize', customeResize(canvas,canId)); within init() method and     function customeResize(canvas,canId){
        ratio = 400 / 800;
        canvas.width =
        document.body.clientWidth < 800 ? document.body.clientWidth : 800;
        canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
        initEditableImageCanvas(canId);}     
    } but this is not working

Comment: Can you update your code in your question so I can better understand what you mean?

Comment: I don't know jquery nor do I want to learn it. I have update my snippet with two canvas's and two images where they both resize. You'll just want to set the positioning as you see fit.

Comment: thanks your answer was helpful . I will accept your answer

Comment: Hi Justin, why drawing is removed on resizing the browser? how to fix this.Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. The images in the snippet I posted above don't disappear when I resize the browser.

Comment: I mean when you paint on the image and resize the browser size to small one, paint disappear from the image. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: if the canvas is in col-sm-6 i want to show small canvas and if it is in col-sm-12 div i want to show bigger canvas how can i do this?